# Problem using sqlconnection in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2000

My code:

```
String dbDate = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox3.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy", null).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");

SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=hcgoa;User Id=sa;Password=;");
MyConnection.Open();
String MyString = "select notice from notice_aspx where fil_no=? and orderdate=?";
SqlCommand MyCmd = new SqlCommand(MyString, MyConnection);
MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value);
MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dbDate);
using (SqlDataReader MyReader4 = MyCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    //**
    if (MyReader4.Read())
    {

        String MyString1 = "UPDATE notice_aspx SET notice=? where fil_no=? AND orderdate=?";
        SqlCommand MyCmd1 = new SqlCommand(MyString1, MyConnection);
        MyCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Editor1.Content.ToString());
        MyCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", HiddenField4.Value.ToString());
        MyCmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dbDate);
        MyCmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {.........
```

ERROR is

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '?'.
Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '?'.
```

How to correct the error. Is it because i cant use '?' ? Please help to sort the problem.

Comment: Have you tried changing the ?s with actual parameters? Like @param1 @param2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that for SQL server you need to use *named* parameters instead of *positional* parameters. See the documentation for [`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example. So your SQL would be:

```
select notice from notice_aspx where fil_no=@fil and orderdate=@orderdate
```

(and you'd then specify those names when adding the parameters).

Note that this has nothing to do with ASP.NET - you should be able to check this in a small console app. (You should also have `using` statements for your connection and command, btw.)